# How to build a data-driven menu in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, user-interface

I'm going to attempt to build a data-driven menu for my web-app.  The goal is to be able to serve different menu options to different users from an API.  The hope is that the server could return a JSON object that defines the menu.  The challenge I'm facing is how to define what the menu options *do*.

```
let menu = {
  "settings": {
    "label": "Settings",
    "icon": "settings.png",
    "type": "menu",
    "subitems": {
        "darkmode": {
          "label": "Dark Mode",
          "type": "toggle",
          "???": "???"
        },
        "other": {
          "label": "Some other setting",
          "type": "action",
        },
    } 
  },
  "profile": {
    "label": "Profile",
    "icon": "profile.png",
    "type": "link",
  }
}
```

It would be easy enough to iterate through the object and populate the menus, but in the example data above, how might I "toggle" the dark mode setting?

The only thought I've come up with is to have it be a link to something like "index.html?action=toggleDarkMode" then perform the appropriate method.  This is obviously not ideal.

I've done some googling for "Javascript Data Driven Menu" but haven't had much luck.  It's mostly dynamic drop downs or straight up nav links.

I've also determined/discovered it's a bad idea to just define methods in the JSON.

Sorry if this question is too vague, but any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: who is calling this api and why do they want your menu rather than their own?

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: yes. it seems like an api can't provide a menu for random applications, how would it know what pages are on the website calling it?

Comment: There are no "random applications"... I'm building a webapp.  I'm calling the API.  User A might get menu items that User B does not, as defined in a database.

Comment: It's not a public API.

Comment: then you dont need to indicate what they do. just an id, hook your menu.click javascript onto the elements and have a big conditional. if id==darkmode then toggleDarkMode()

Comment: That is one option. Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to have `action` key for each of "acting" menu items, e.g.

```
let menu = {
    ...
    "darkmode": {
        ...
        "action": "toggleDarkMode",
    },
    ...
};
```

You may have an object listing all possible actions, e.g.

```
let actions = {
    toggleDarkMode: toggleDarkMode, // a function defined somwhere else
    yetAnotherAction: () => { console.log('ACTION!'); },
};
```

Now assuming you have `menuItem` referring to either of "acting" menu items you may just call `actions[menuItem.action]();`

The problem is that any your action can be called (e.g. using developers console) disregarding the fact it is not referred to in your `menu`.

Hope the above helps.